# Convert Excel VB Macro to Mac compatible

Tags: macos, vba, excel, phpexcel

I have the following VB Macro for taking a large Excel file and splitting it into many smaller files each consisting of 1,000 rows (999 of data, 1 row for headers).

```
Sub SplitExcelFile()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim RangeOfHeader As Range        'data (range) of header row
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile                    'how many rows (incl. header) in new files?

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Initialize data
  Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1
  RowsInFile = 1000                  '1000 rows per file

  'Copy the data of the first row (header)
  Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))

  For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    'Paste the header row in new file
    RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    'Paste the chunk of rows for this file
    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
    RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

    'Save the new workbook, and close it
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "/File_" & WorkbookCounter & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
    wb.Close

    'Increment file counter
    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
  Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

It works perfectly on PC, but when I run it on Mac, it says error regarding object not defined.  So I thought okay it must be the Path separator is not a "\", must be a "/".  So I change that and it seemed to run okay.  It created the files at least.  However, when I try to open them on a PC it shows error stating the following:

```
The file format and extension of 'File_1.xls' don't match.  The file could be corrupted or unsafe.  Unless you trust its source, don't open it.  Do you want to open it anyway?
```

This causes problems when I try to open it with PHPExcel on the website where it is being used.  Any ideas as to why this happens and how I can correct it?

Comment: Maybe try the suggested formats here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm

Comment: Rather than hard code the `/` or `\ ` , use `Application.PathSeparator`

Comment: @chrisneilsen excellent suggestion, thank you!!!